# Xcode 10.1 freezes while compiling

Tags: xcode, macos

I updated Xcode to 10.1 version, but every time I run or compile my project the whole mac hangs and freezes,  which makes me shutdown iMac or mac logs out automatically! Why does this happen? I literally cannot work or build and run anything! I updated java, macOS, closing all apps, but still freezes all the time. have you any solution?

Comment: I have this problem too.
It started after updating Xcode to 10.1, and sometime during compilation the computer freezes and the only thing that works is rebooting computer.
And no, CMD+CTRL+ESC does not bring forward a Force Quit dialog, and no, I don't think it is RAM/disk space, as it started happening after the update, but not for all projects. Some projects compile just fine. Yesterday,
I tried downloading Xcode 10.0 again, deleted Derived data, cleaned, and then it compiled just fine. But it would not push the app to my phone, because Xcode 10.0 does not work with iOS 12.1.
What to do?

Comment: Yeah, this is my exact problem! I downgraded Xcode, if you want to run on your device download this disk image:
https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image

Comment: java would be completely unrelated as Xcode doesn't build or use java.

Comment: Xcode 10.2 beta is out. I fixed my problem by removing all my SCNViews alltogether, to add them in the code, as I have described in an answer below, which made it work, so I cannot tell if 10.2 beta solved the problem.

Comment: Just to add, this has been happening to me since 10.1 update, and still does, on big project with 5 SCNViews. A weird note is that, when I leave my iMac at its frozen state overnight, I wake up in the morning to see that it has finished compiling, and it will not crash again unless more Views added to any storyboard. This is a weird one, but happens everytime in my case - it eventually "unfreezes" after 3-4-5-6 hours

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having the exact problem, so I watched my build tasks click by. It turns out I was suffering a full system freeze during the

> Compile Storyboard file...

step of my Main storyboard file. (My Storyboard wasn't terribly large. ~10 View Controllers)

I recreated my project and, for me, the instability came about when I began adding a couple SCNViews. When I removed them all, and programmatically created those views, my Storyboard compile step passed and my app launched.

I'm not sure it's specifically SceneKit causing issues, but *something* was causing my Storyboard to fail compilation. It's worth a start to try there: backup the project, delete everything in the Storyboard, and see if you're still crashing. (This definitely wasn't happening under 10.0)

Comment: Yeah - definitely didn't mean to imply starting over was the best option! Just curious: do you know what Build Task you're crashing on? (is it also the Storyboard Compile task?) And are you using SceneKit or SpriteKit - or just using standard UIKit views?

Comment: Yes I am using SceneKit,ARKit still waiting  fixes this issue

Comment: Great to know that your issue may also be SceneKit related. I'm trying to build up a test case, proving failure, and then will submit a bug report to Apple. Follow-up question: what hardware are you on? (my crash logs also showed a Metal related crash, so I'm wondering if it's related to graphics card drivers and SceneKit) I'm on a 2017 13" MacBook Pro (GPU: Intel Iris Plus 640)

Comment: Great! I have several SceneKit views in Storyboard myself, and I didn't suspect it to be SCNView and Storyboard related. I did copy the project over and used an older git version and then add the new methods and StoryBoard items one by one, and gradually the problem came back.
So if there's no new Xcode out soon, I should try to figure out how to add them programmatically.

Comment: @GPurcell I am also having the same issue. I have 4-5 SCNViews in the storyboard and during compilation it literally hang. I hope this issue will get resolved in Xcode 11.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Analysis**
Based on G Purcell's answer, I concentrated my focus on my SCNViews. This made it stop crashing (removing subtype names for all SCNViews):

[image]

But I could not make the custom classes initialize properly. I wouldn't work for me casting them at runtime to their subtypes, and XCode was still crashing sometimes.

**2. The fix**
There was no other way than writing code, and I am including it here, only if anyone else needed some help initializing the SCNViews programmatically (I struggled, first tried keeping the generic SCNViews.) So I removed all SCNViews alltogether (OK, not all - it still compiles with the two-three SCNViews in StoryBoard,) and added a UIView as a placeholder with the same constraints as before.

**SCNView subclass**:

First make sure the init(frame:) method is implemented -- in the case there is something going on in the init, add a custom init func, so it is called from either init:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame, options: nil)
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.customInit()
}
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    customInit()
}
func customInit(){
    self.sceneSetup()
    self.intro()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

**ViewController**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.customSceneView = CustomSceneView(frame: customSceneContainer.bounds)
    self.customSceneContainer.addSubview(self.customSceneView)
    self.customSceneView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customSceneContainer.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    self.customSceneView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customSceneContainer.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
}
```

**Result**:
Finally everything compiled, my Mac stayed awake. Some new additional constraints needed to be added for correct resizing when rotating the device. But at last, and after two months, I could upload new features to the App Store. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite surprised that an app can freeze the entire Mac, even an app that comes from Apple.

After a lot of frustration with this issue I found the following workaround that works for me:

1. Build the app until the Mac freezes.
2. Wait a little bit longer (10-20 seconds).
3. Hold down the Mac's power button until it turns off.
4. Turn on your Mac.
5. Open the main storyboard and slightly move one of the view controllers.
6. Save the storyboard and open any other file.
7. Build the app again - This time the Mac does not freeze

Any rebuild works fine for me as long as the storyboard was not touched.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve above issue, by removing SCNView and ARSCNview from storyboard. Had to create ARSCNView and SCNView programatically. App had total 20 ViewControllers, out of which 5 contained ARSCNView and 1 SCNView. After that successfully compiled the build in Xcode 10.1, Xcode 10.2 beta 4.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the git repo then recloned it, seemed to fix the problem